# Hamming code parity check matrix.

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Let's say we have a matrix

$ H= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Which is a hamming code parity check matrix

I need to find code generator matrix and then find code words if sequence being sent is $ 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0$

Now, when i find code generator matrix, its dimensions are supposed to be 4x7. Since i have a sequence of twelve numbers. How am i supposed to determine the code words when number of elements in a given sequence is not equal to number of rows of generator matrix so multiplication of that vector and generator matrix is not possible? Any help appreciated!

Comment: In block coding, when using an $(n,k)$ block code, the message to be transmitted is split into blocks of $k$ bits. These are then encoded  to match what you would get when using a prescribed generator matrix.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Does this mean that i need to code this segment part by part, in such way that i first take first four bit and code them, then bits from 5th to 8th and so on... Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for help!  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered to some satisfaction in the comment by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), as written by the poster in another comment.

From the comments:

"In block coding, when using an (n,k) block code, the message to be transmitted is split into blocks of k bits. These are then encoded to match that you would get when using a prescribed generator matrix."